# Select Multiple counts from the same table based on range

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I have a ms access table in the following format

```
request_date        | Total_Uploaded
24/03/2015 07:42:47 |     36
24/03/2015 07:56:19 |     36
24/03/2015 08:17:28 |     4
24/03/2015 08:33:04 |     4
24/03/2015 08:39:07 |     36
24/03/2015 08:53:56 |     10
24/03/2015 09:04:26 |     16
24/03/2015 09:14:03 |     6
24/03/2015 09:14:05 |     16
24/03/2015 09:18:32 |     407
24/03/2015 09:18:34 |     16
24/03/2015 09:19:00 |     13
24/03/2015 09:19:05 |     62
24/03/2015 09:25:59 |     138
24/03/2015 09:27:08 |     138
24/03/2015 09:28:02 |     16
24/03/2015 09:31:09 |     16
```

I want to be able to get counts per hour of records between a set of ranges. my ranges are

- 0 - 10
- 11 - 50
- 51 - 100
- > 101

so I would like to end up with a table that shows

```
DateTime |      0-10 Count| 22-50 Count| 51-100 Count | > 100 Count
24/03/2015 07        0    |      2     |     0        |     0   
24/03/2015 08        2    |      1     |     0        |     0
```

I have been able to group by date by using datepart("h", request_date) and get any one of the range counts but I would like my query to be able to do all of them in one hit. I have tried sub query but it ends up very messy and mainly Wrong. any input gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is Access, here is how:

```
SELECT 
    Format([request_date],"dd\/mm\/yyyy hh") AS DateHour, 
    Count(TableTotals.total_uploaded) AS Count_all, 
    Count(IIf([total_uploaded]<=10,1,Null)) AS Count_0_to_10, 
    Count(IIf([total_uploaded] Between 11 And 50,1,Null)) AS Count_11_to_50, 
    Count(IIf([total_uploaded] Between 51 And 100,1,Null)) AS Count_51_to_100, 
    Count(IIf([total_uploaded]>100,1,Null)) AS Count_101_up
FROM 
    TableTotals 
GROUP BY 
    DateValue([request_date]), 
    Hour([request_date]), 
    Format([request_date],"dd\/mm\/yyyy hh");
```

Output:

```
DateHour    Count_all   Count_0_to_10   Count_11_to_50  Count_51_to_100 Count_101_up
24/03/2015 07   2   0   2   0   0
24/03/2015 08   4   3   1   0   0
24/03/2015 09   11  1   6   1   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [case](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php) inside a sum for each column. In the case you transform a value in the particular range to 1 and other values to 0.

Answer (score 0):

SUM each sub query to get your totals per group, then group by date/hour

```
SELECT request_date AS DateTime,  SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Uploaded BETWEEN 0 AND 10 
                               THEN 1 
                               ELSE 0 END) AS [0-10 Count],  
                      SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Uploaded BETWEEN 22 AND 50 
                               THEN 1 
                               ELSE 0 END) AS [22-50 Count],
                      SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Uploaded BETWEEN 51 AND 100 
                               THEN 1 
                               ELSE 0 END) AS [51-100 Count],
                      SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Uploaded > 100 
                               THEN 1 
                               ELSE 0 END) AS [> 100 Count]
FROM table
GROUP BY  CAST(request_date as date), DATEPART(hour,request_date)
```